# Dynamic Filter value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to use a dynamic value for a filter variable in this manner:

```
<div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" >
    <a class="view-detail" ng-href="#/playlist/{{playlist.id}}">{{playlist.playlistName}}</a>
    <a ng-href="#/playlist/{{playlist.id}}">check out this playlist >></a>
    <span ng-repeat="genre in genres | filter:{name:'playlist.playlistGenre'}">
        <img ng-src="{{genre.image}}">  
    </span>
</div>
```

As such its a repeat within a repeat - its not showing up like this, however if i hardcode in one of the values that the filter variable would return, then it works -

Or should i rethink my approach -

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
filter:{name:'playlist.playlistGenre'}
```

That looks for genres whose name is the string 'playlist.playlistGenre'. What you want, if I understand correctly, is to display the genres whose name has the same value as the field `playlistGenre` of the `playlist`.

So you want

```
filter:{name:playlist.playlistGenre}
```

That said, this is quite inefficient. I guess there is a single genre that has a given name. So, instead of looping through all genres for each playlist, you'd better set the genre directly in the playlist, or at least use a hash that contains the genre for every name:

```
$scope.genresByName = {};
genres.forEach(function(genre) {
    $scope.genresByName[genre.name] = genre;
});
```

and then

```
<div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" >
    <a class="view-detail" ng-href="#/playlist/{{playlist.id}}">{{playlist.playlistName}}</a>
    <a ng-href="#/playlist/{{playlist.id}}">check out this playlist >></a>
    <span><img ng-src="{{genresByName[playlist.playlistGenre].image}}"></span>
</div>
```